# Stripe undefined method customer_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

So I currently have this booking functionality that I am trying to add a payment system to using **Stripe**

However, when I try to submit my credit card details form I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `customer_id' for #<User:0x552abc0>):

app/services/credit_card_service.rb:8:in `create_credit_card'
app/controllers/charges_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

When I look at the code in the files that are specified in the error above this is what is there:

```
#app/controllers/charges_controller.rb


class ChargesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :find_product

  def create
    stripe_card_id =
      if params[:credit_card].present?
        CreditCardService.new(current_user.id, card_params).create_credit_card
      else
        charge_params[:card_id]
      end

    Stripe::Charge.create(
      customer: current_user.customer_id,
      source:   stripe_card_id,
      amount:   @booking.price_in_cents,
      currency: 'usd'
    )

    if params[:credit_card].present? && stripe_card_id
      current_user.credit_cards.create_with(card_params).find_or_create_by(stripe_id: stripe_card_id)
    end
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to @booking
  end

  private

  def card_params
    params.require(:credit_card).permit(:number, :month, :year, :cvc)
  end

  def charge_params
    params.require(:charge).permit(:card_id)
  end

  def find_product
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:booking_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    flash[:error] = 'Booking not found!'
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

and

```
class CreditCardService
  def initialize(user_id, card)
    @user = User.find(user_id)
    @card = card
  end

  def create_credit_card
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.customer_id)
    customer.sources.create(source: generate_token).id
  end

  def generate_token
    Stripe::Token.create(
      card: {
        number: @card[:number],
        exp_month: @card[:month],
        exp_year: @card[:year],
        cvc: @card[:cvc]
      }
    ).id
  end
end
```

Any help or tips on how to tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated.

I have used devise for my user login/registration

Comment: add `customer_id` field in users table

Comment: Do you have `customer_id` in users table?

Comment: @Pavan would i just do that with : rails g migration add_customer_id_to_users customer_id:integer ??

Comment: @noob-on-rails Stripe customer id look like a token `cust_id_xxxxx` so column data type should be string ie `rails g migration add_customer_id_to_users customer_id`

Answer (score 0):

Afaik,

You need to create a customer in Stripe itself

Ex:

`response = Stripe::Customer.create({ email: 'email@example.com' })`

then store the response in new migration column using,

`response[:id] which return customer_id from stripe`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, it looks like your `User`-model simply doesn't have a `customer_id` attribute on it.  You'd need to define that and store the Stripe Customer ID (as Nithin suggested above).